# Give macro access to protected sheets

Tags: vba, excel, security

I have an application built in MS Excel using VBA. I originally protected some worksheets and the VBA project by password. My users can only input and use drop downs on specific cells in specific sheets. To let my VBA modify the protected sheets I had to unprotect the sheets and then reprotect them using the password.

The requirement of the project has now changed and now requires me not to have a hard coded string for the password in the code to protect and unprotect the sheets.

A code sample of what is going on in my VBA code is the following.

```
Worksheets("Loading").Unprotect ("****")
[Functional Code]
Worksheets("Loading").Protect ("****")
```

Considering that I have to have the password to gain access to the VBA project is there a way to allow the project to interact with protected sheets as if they were not protected?

If no. Is there another method of preventing user interaction with a sheet while not inhibiting VBA interaction ( Very hidden would not work for the user still needs to see the sheet ).

Side note: This needs to prevent a normal person with minimal technical skills from altering the sheets in ways that they shouldn't

Answer (score 3):

On an unprotected worksheet use,

```
Worksheets("Loading").Protect Password:=****, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

See [Worksheet.Protect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx) for full details. Once it has been set with this extra parameter and the workbook has been saved, the protection will be bypassed by any VBA code but remain in place for user interaction.

Comment: When I reopen my workbook UserInterfaceOnly is set to false. How would I go about setting it to true without having to rerun ````.Protect````

Comment: My explanation may have been terse. My purpose was to introduce you to the UserInterfaceOnly parameter. You still need to set the protection with a password and save the workbook.

Comment: The issue is that I can't use ````Worksheets("Loading").Protect Password:=****, UserInterfaceOnly:=True```` for it still requires me to have the password in the code. UserInterfaceOnly needs to be set each time the workbook is opened and requires the password to set it.

Comment: >You should be aware that if you apply the Protect with the UserInterfaceOnly argument set to True to a worksheet and then save and close the workbook, the entire worksheet will be fully protected when you reopen the workbook, but the interface protection is no longer applied.This means that to re-enable the user interface protection you must again apply the Protect method with UserInterfaceOnly set to True each time you open the workbook. (Taken from http://www.excel-it.com/excel_userinterfaceonly.html )